# Create magento different language store

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have created two different stores for different languages on Magento 1.9. But, I am unable to see language drop-down at the frontend. Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

The store switcher does not appear unless you have **2 stores minimum** in the current website.

- Check if you have well this file : `/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/page/switch/languages.phtml` else in your `base/default`
- Check well if you have the code bellow in your xml `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`

  ```
  <reference name="top.links">
      <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
  </reference>
  ```